# Am I interpreting this subgroup of the permutations of $n$ elements $S_n$ correctly?

Tags: group-theory, permutations

I am asked to prove $H=\{\sigma \in S_n:n\sigma=n\}$ is a subgroup of $S_n$.

Am I correct in thinking this is the set of all permutations that map any element from $\{1,2,...,n\}$ to itself? That is this set has only one element that is the identity map on $n$ elements $\text{id} _n$ (is that the notation?).

So the proof is trivial since it is the trivial subgroup (and hence obviously a subgroup)?

Or am I messing this up completely?

Thanks.

Comment: No: this is the subgroup of permutations fixing the element $n$, possibly permuting all other elements $\{ 1, \dots , n-1 \}$.

Comment: This subgroup can be identified in a natural way with $S_{n-1}$.

Comment: The subgroup that you describe would be given by $\{\sigma \in S_n : k\sigma = k \text{ for each } k = 1, 2, \ldots, n\}$; a different symbol, rather than $n$, is needed to indicate that every element is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The set $H$ is defined to be the set of all permutations in $S_n$ that maps the symbol $n$ to itself.  This subgroup has $(n-1)!$ elements, and is isomorphic to $S_{n-1}$.